# media-query for mobile not working

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm trying to use media-queries in my CSS for the first time, but I don't seem to be having much luck getting it to work.

To test, I wanted my #page-wrap to resize to 440px when something like an iPhone is looking at the page, but nothing changes.
This is what I've used.

`@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
 #page-wrap {width:440px;}
 }`

I also put this in my header.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Is this correct?

Comment: are you checking with your browser? if so, you have to delete device in device-width and as well screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a specific reason you're using `max-device-width`?  Unlike `max-width`, it will not help with people rotating their device or other types of adjustments.

Instead, stick to using `max-width`, like the following:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) { 
    #page-wrap {
        width:100px;
    } 
}
```

Check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vVjtA/) that illustrates it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for your media query:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {}
```